# why ant print time with a slash?

Tags: ant, properties

I have this date format:

```
<entry key="buildDate" type="date" value="now" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

But **ant** gives me this result (in a  key-value properties file):

```
buildDate=01-13-2012 14\:19\:59
```

Why **ant** add those slash in? because it is in a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The colons have special meaning in a Java properties file (they can act as key-value separators), so Ant needs to escape them with backslashes.

Comment: Ant doesn't escape anything, it's Java !

Comment: @Rebse: It's not Java either, it's the implementation of `Properties.store` that does it. Besides, it's hardly a distinction that matters, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Ant doesn't add those `\`, it's Java.

See api docs for [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), especially the [store(Writer writer, String comments)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

> The key and element characters `#`, `!`, `=`, and `:` are written with a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.